# Logging and event tracer on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any way of getting merged logs from more than one deployments on Kybernetes? What's the best way of logging events for all deployments?

Answer (score 1):

Look for Elasticsearch , Logstash and Kibana (ELK) stack with Filebeats or FluentD to ship log data from individual deployments/pods onto your Elasticsearch DB. Once data is in your DB , use Kibana to visualize and search your merged logs. Logstash can be used to modify your data inflight. A simple google search should yield you lot of resources on doing the same.